# MySQL Workbench - Table Data Import Wizard writing all datetime objects as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, csv, date, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0 atop a MariaDB (`'10.1.37-MariaDB'`) server.

I'm trying to use the **Table Data Import Wizard** to import 3 example values into a table. Here is an example of what the CSV looks like:

```
emp_id,Event,Event_start_time,Event_end_time,
example,shift,"2020/11/6 0:00:00","6/11/2020 23:59",
example,lunch,"2020/14/06 13:00:00","2020/14/06 13:30:00",
example,break,"2020/14/06 10:10:00","2020/14/06 10:30:00",
```

During the import, every value appears correctly, save for the Datetime fields (`Event_start_time`, `Event_end_time`), which appear as `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` after running a `select` statement.

I have tried the following formats, and none seem to work:

- `"2020/11/6 0:00:00"`
- `2020/11/6 0:00:00`
- `2020/11/06 00:00:00`
- `2020-11-06 00:00:00`

The following case was successful:

- `2020-11-06 0:00`

But I need to be able to include seconds for business logic.

Even worse, when I export my table (with existing Datetime values) to a `.csv` using the same wizard, and then try to reimport, all of the values load as `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`. As I'm developing a solution for someone else, **I'd like to minimize/avoid MySQL scripting as much as I can. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Have you tried replacing `/` with `-`?

Comment: Note one of your dates is just plain messed up: `6/11/2020`.

Comment: Alright, so the bottom two cases didn't return the correct answer, but the top one (2020-11-06 0:00) did. The only difference in the cases is the inclusion of seconds. Is there any way for me to be able to include seconds without returning blank values?

Comment: What is the LOCALE setting?

Comment: en_US is the locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates seem to be in `YYYY/DD/MM HH:MI:SS` format, which is not valid from MySQL perspective. You would need to turn them to format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` so the database can properly recognize them.

If you have your data in a CSV file, a simple option is the [`LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) with input pre-processing. Based on the sample data that you are showing, this should look like:

```
load data infile 'myfile.csv'
into mytable (emp_id, event, @event_start_time, @event_end_time)
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
ignore 1 lines
set 
    event_start_time = str_to_date(@event_start_time, '%Y/%d/%m %H:%i:%s'),
    event_end_time   = str_to_date(@event_end_time,   '%Y/%d/%m %H:%i:%s')
```

You might need to adjust the statement options - and possibly the target date format - to your actual use acse.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the values incorrectly.

2020-11-06 0:00:00 `(Y-M-D)` is **correct**.
2020-14-06 0:00:00 `(Y-D-M)` is **incorrect**.